# Averaging time series groups and plotting them against one another

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse

In the time series data created below `data`, individuals (denoted by a unique `ID`) were sampled from 2 populations (`NC` and `SC`). All individuals have the same number of observations. I want to average the data for each respective "time point" for all individuals that belong to the same "State" (the average line) and I want to plot the average lines from each state against each other. I want it to look something like this:

[image]

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
ID <- rep(1:10, each = 500)
Time = rep(c(1:500),10)
Location = rep(c("NC","SC"), each = 2500)
Var <- rnorm(5000)
data <- data.frame(
  ID = factor(ID),
  Time = Time,
  State = Location,
  Variable = Var
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend getting familiar with the various `dplyr` functions. Specifically, `group_by` and `summarise`. You may want to read through: [Introduction to dplyr](https://stat545.com/dplyr-intro.html) or going through [this series](https://suzanbaert.netlify.com/2018/01/dplyr-tutorial-1/) of blog posts.

In short, we are grouping the data by the `Time` and `State` variable and then summarizing that data with an average (i.e., `mean(Variable)`). To plot the data, we put `Time` on our x-axis, the newly created `avg_var` on our y-axis, and use `State` to represent color. These are assigned as our chart's aesthetics (i.e., `aes(...)`. Finally, we add the line geom with `geom_line()` to render the lines on our visualization.

```
data %>% 
    group_by(Time, State) %>%
    summarise(avg_var = mean(Variable)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = avg_var, color = State)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]